# Can Flask-SQLAlchemy's Pagination class be used with a Python list?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a list of posts that I queried from SQLAlchemy. However, it's just a Python list now, not a query, so I can't use Flask-SQLAlchemy's `query.paginate()` method. Is it possible to use Flask-SQLAlchemy's `Paginate` class to paginate the list instead of a query?

```
from  flask_sqlalchemy import Pagination
from flask_app.model import Post
 
recommended_posts_title = ['the sea', 'loving better', 'someones mother']
posts = [Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first() for title in recommended_posts_title]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Flask-SQLAlchemy's `Pagination` class, but need to manually get the page number and slice the data.

The [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination) show the parameters that `Pagination` takes: `Pagination(query, page, per_page, total, items)`.

Since we don't have a query in this case, we'll pass `None` for `query`. We'll get the `page` from the query string (`http://localhost/home/posts?page=1`), and use 20 for `per_page`. We can get `total` with `len()`, then slice our data to get 20 `items` from the page offset.

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import Pagination
from flask import Flask,request,render_template
from flask_app.model import Post

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/recommended-posts", methods = ['GET'])
def recommended_post():
    recommended_titles = ['the sea', 'loving better', 'someones mother']
    posts = [Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first() for title in titles]
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    # get the start and end index based on page number
    start = (page - 1) * 20
    end = start + 20
    # page 1 is [0:20], page 2 is [20:41]
    items = posts[start:end]
    pagination = Pagination(None, page, 20, len(items), items)
    return render_template('blog/posts.html', pagination=pagination)
```

Use the pagination object as you normally would.

```html
{% for item in pagination.items %}
    render post
{% endfor %}

{% if pagination.has_prev %}
    <a href="{{ url_for("recommended_posts", page=pagination.prev_num) }}">Previous</a>
{% endif %}

{% if pagination.has_next %}
    <a href="{{ url_for("recommended_posts", page=pagination.next_num) }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not able to retrieve all results via a single query in my application, so couldn't use the `query.paginate()` functionality out of the box and had to resort to a custom "pagination" of my retrieved list of results. This code helped me to get this done. 

One remark: I believe your `total = len(items)` should be replaced by `total = len(posts)`, otherwise your total pages will always be 1.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is still worth after more than a year:

I recently encountered the same issue since my results could not be obtained from a single query and had to be build it iteratively resulting in a "list of results".

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835849/18201892), I came up with the following function to convert a list of results to a `Pagination` object:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import Pagination

def paginate(data, page, per_page):
    # Based on page and per_page info, calculate start and end index of items to keep
    start_index = (page - 1) * per_page
    end_index = start_index + per_page

    # Get the paginated list of items
    items = data[start_index:end_index]

    # Create Pagination object
    return Pagination(None, page, per_page, len(data), items)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for future users and a really clean and simple solution, I hope it works for you.
***I was running into the same problem not being able to use paginate in Flask-SQLAlchemy because its not compatible with lists***...

*I tried using other library's but its an understatement to say they were cumbersome and didn't have enough features built in.*

```
def project(page, proj_type='mini'):
    per_page = 3
    return ProjectPost.query.filter(ProjectPost.type == proj_type).paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page, error_out=False)
```

**type** is a column in my dB, I have three **types** and each one is for a different page with pagination.

So **Filter()** returns the query object itself, allowing us to chain more query options aka paginate...

On the other hand **filter_by()** returns the query objects but also calls **all()** method on the query object automatically so it returns a **list** of matched results.

TLDR: use **filter()** for chaining operations and keep them as objects.

Answer (score -2):

You need to read https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination So what you need to do is build query object from sqlalchemy. Then you pass that query object to `Pagnination` class to get an object and then you simply pass that to your template.